# iterate over data from a route in a template

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a cursor returned from a route, how can I use the data as context in a template?

example:

router.js

this will return a cursor with all documents where `parent` is equal to the `params_id`

```
this.route('my route', {
    path: '/myroute:_id',
    data: function(){
        return MyCollection.find({parent: this.params._id});
    }
});
```

how should my template look like to "iterate" over the cursor? normally if I use `MyCollection.find({})` I iterate with `#each` and give the context a name via a TemplateHelper. I guess

```
{{#each data}}....{{/each}}
```

should be right but it doesn´t work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `data` in the route sets the context for the template. In the template, the context is accessed via `this`:

```
{{#each this}}...{{/each}}
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to assign a name to your data, can return an object from the route:

```js
data: function(){
  return {posts: Posts.find({parent: this.params._id})};
}
```

And then you can iterate over the documents like so:

```
{{#each posts}}...{{/each}}
```